# Apache isis - change welcome page

Tags: isis

I'm using `Apache ISIS` with `Shiro Auth`.

I'd like to change the welcome page.

I know that the welcome file is defined on web.xml, but I have to startup the app at the login page(this one: myhost/signin). Can someone tell me how can I do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach is to just replace index.html (in src/main/webapp) with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=wicket/"/>
</head>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could map the Wicket servlet to "/" (instead of "wicket/").